# Handling giant objects in a chrome extension? - Performance?

Tags: javascript, json, performance, google-chrome, object

I made a chrome extension to gather information from a website and react if something specific happens.

I broke down my code a bit to make it easier to understand what I am doing here.

This requires me to request a "database" object via jQuery getJson. After parsing the database, it's an object with 20 arrays (of objects).

```
var database = {

            "topicA" : [
                            {"title" : "example123", "name" : "example123", "price" : "1.99", "id" : "238431"},
                            {"title" : "example456", "name" : "example456", "price" : "4.99", "id" : "23248431"},
                            {"title" : "example789", "name" : "example789", "price" : "2.99", "id" : "123841"},
                    ],

            "topicB" : [
                            {"title" : "book123", "name" : "aBook123", "price" : "13.99", "id" : "12231"}
                    ],

            "topicC" : [                    
                            {"title" : "paper123", "name" : "aPaper123", "price" : "4.99", "id" : "1234321"},
                            {"title" : "paper345", "name" : "anotherPaper123", "price" : "0.99", "id" : "1322431"}
                    ]
}
```

It does not matter from which "topic" a single item came from, they are all treated the same.
After receiving the database, I am pushing all the objects from the inner arrays into a big one to have one function run over each of them. This array now holds ~15.000 objects with around 6 or 7 properties, each having a value of 10-50 characters.

```
    var itemArray = [];
    var fullInventory = {};

         //get the JSON

    $.getJSON(databaseURL, function(json){  

        fullInventory = json;

        for (var key in fullInventory) { 

         //push all items (inner objects) into a single array

            for(i = 0; i < fullInventory[key].length; i++) {
                itemArray.push(fullInventory[key][i]);
            }
        }

        checkItems();

    });
```

Here is a little more understandable version of what I am doing with the big array:

```
    function checkItems() {

        for (i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {

            var name = itemArray[i].name;
            var id = itemArray[i].id;
            var price = parseFloat(itemArray[i].price);

            if(bookNames.indexOf(name) >= 0 && blackList.indexOf(id) == 0) {

                blackList.push(id); //blackList is defined as an empty array when the page is opened.

                console.log(name + " is " + price + "€! ID: " + id);

            }

        }

        setTimeout(function() { getNewDatabase() }, 30 * 1000); //After 30 seconds, it loads the database again

    }
```

My code works fine, but after some time (an hour maybe), chrome closes the website with a message like "reached RAM limit". How would I avoid this? In the long run, I would like to run this extension on my raspberryPi. Doing this right now, crashes Chromium after ~15 reloads. How can I avoid a massive RAM usage? How could I get this more efficient?

Yes, I know that this would usually be a job for something like node, but this requires a login, cookies and some on-page actions if a specific "case" happens and I am not too good with node yet, but need this project to work for atleast a time soon.

Any tips are greatly appreciated, I am still kind of new to JS. :)
Thank you!

Comment: why fetch the entire database over and over? usually that's the backend's job. if you don't have access to a backend try to split up your "database" into several json files (different endpoints) and use the frontend logic to determine which store you should fetch. that should greatly reduce the size of the store you are looping through.

Comment: @Daniel_L This seems to be my only way of reacting fast to changes that are happening. There is no API or something similar. I also never know which item changes, I have to go through the whole thing. How would I split up the JSON? Just use 3 arrays instead of a giant one? Would looping through the "topic" arrays one by one be better than putting them all into one array?